# Boilerplate code for inflating multiple layouts in a fragment

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

Let's assume I have two xml  layouts: `progbarlayout` & `linearlayout`  and a fragment with this

```
 TextView mTxtDisplay;
 ImageView mImageView;
 mTxtDisplay = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtDisplay);
 String url = "http://my-json-feed";

 JsonObjectRequest jsObjRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, null, new Response.Listener < JSONObject > () {    
       
     @Override  
     public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {    
         mTxtDisplay.setText("Response: " + response.toString());  
     }
 }, new Response.ErrorListener() {    
       
     @Override  
     public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {    
         // TODO Auto-generated method stub
     }
 });

 // Access the RequestQueue through your singleton class.
 MySingleton.getInstance(this).addToRequestQueue(jsObjRequest);
```

Is it possible to inflate `progbarlayout` in the fragment's `onCreateView` then in the JsonObjectRequest's `onResponse` remove the `progbarlayout` layout and inflate `linearlayout`?

If yes, can you please include a code snippet to demonstrate how?

Comment: What you want to achieve ?

Comment: You can inflate the first layout, but if you want to inflate another one you have to recreate the fragment. What's the point of your question?

Comment: @Haroon I have updated my question.

Comment: @MachoProgrammer I have edited my question.

Comment: @MachoProgrammer what does `addview and `removeview` do? Can't I do it that way?

Comment: Usually the addview is used when you want to add in a layout, for example a linearlayout, a new view, for example a textview.